A nice description of a specific toric variety
I am reading through Fulton's Introduction to Toric Varieties and working out some of the exercises. In chapter 1.4. we are asked to find the toric varieties associated to some specific fans on $N=\mathbb{Z}^2$.
I am having trouble giving a nice description for the toric variety associated to
this fan:

It is clear to me that the whole left part is $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{P}^1$, but the right ray $\tau$ is throwing me off as to how it changes $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{P}^1$, i.e. how it is glued.
The group-algebra associated to this ray is $A_{\tau}=\mathbb{C}[x,y,y^{-1}]$, so I can see that the associated affine variety $U_{\tau}$ is a copy of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}^*$ glued to the torus $U_0$ in $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{P}^1$. I don't understand very well how the copy of $\mathbb{C}$ (the one with coordinate $x$) in $U_{\tau}$ is being glued inside of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{P}^1$.
My gut tells me that the way it is being glued leads to something like $(\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{P}^1)\sqcup \{\infty\}$ where this $\infty$ point is the 'point at infinity' for the first copy of $\mathbb{C}$ (in the $x$ coordinate), but it not being glued wholly leads to there just being a point and not the whole line $\{(\infty,x):x\in \mathbb{P}^1\}\subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

I would describe it subtractively - if you add two quadrants to the fan, you get the fan of a toric variety you recognize. Those two quadrants correspond to two points. Now check that removing those points recovers the original toric variety.

That makes a lot of sense! Thank you. Somehow thinking about it 'additively' threw me off.
